# JS Player --- Err : My Return false doesnt work with IE10 but work with all other browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi ive made a mp3 player using javascript, its working perfectly on everybroswer except IE10

Ex of page : http://www.mupiz.com/noon (try to click on a song)

But IE10 follows the link and ignores the script before...

Here's My script :

```
    var list = $("#playlist").find("a:not(.songLink)");
    listNC=new Array();


    for (var i=0;i<list.length;i++) { // we get all the song


        list[i].rel = i; 

        $(list[i]).parent().parent().prepend("<td class='notplayed' width='25px'><img src='../../images/lecteur-B-playlist-play.png' style='z-index:10000'/></td>");
        listNC[i]=girlify(list[i].href);


        list[i].onclick = function(event) { // onclick on each link


                   if($(this).attr('class')!="songLink"){
            soundManager.stopAll(); 
            current = this.rel; 



                event.preventDefault();
                        lire_current(); // this play the song
                       return false; // **this does not work!**

                       }

        };
```

This is the dedicated part of the CSS

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of mix'n'match jQuery with regular DOM code and it's kind of confusing. I think it has only been working in other browsers out of luck on your part. Ultimately, I believe IE is getting an error on your call to `preventDefault` because it has a different event model and you're not using the leveled out jQuery event. This means `preventDefault` doesn't do its job, and the `return false` is never reached due to the error.

I would modify the extracted code as follows:

```
var listNC = [],
    current;

$('#playlist')
    .find('a:not(.songLink)')
    .each(function (i) {
        var $this = $(this);

        $this
            .attr('rel', i)
            .parent()
                .parent()
                    .prepend('<td class="notplayed" width="25px"><img src="../../images/lecteur-B-playlist-play.png" style="z-index:10000"/></td>');

        listNC[i] = girlify($this.attr('href'));
    })
    .on('click', function (e) {
        soundManager.stopAll();
        current = $(this).attr('rel');

        lire_current();

        // Event control:
        e.preventDefault(); //keeps link from being followed

        //I don't think you want either of these next two lines:
        e.stopPropagation(); //keeps event from bubbling...probably not what you want
        return false; //causes same as calling e.preventDefault() e.stopPropagation()...probably not what you want
    });
```

I couldn't test it of course, but I think it will do what you want.

Comment: I post your code online, you was true its an old script js mixed with jquery, but it still does not work with IE10 which follows the links

Comment: Well, I have no way of testing. But `e.preventDefault();` is what you want inside of a jQuery event handler to keep the browser from following the link. Do you see IE10 reporting any errors before it goes off to follow the link? There could be an error anywhere in the handler or the code which it harnesses (`soundManager` code or `lire_current`). Any such error would keep the event handling from being reached. Try making `e.preventDefault()` the first line of the click handling function. If the browser does not follow the link, then you know an error is happening somewhere afterward.

Comment: No errors on the IE10 console before it goes off follow the link. And its working on all other broswer.

Comment: Working in all other browsers doesn't mean anything. IE is notorious for issues which don't generally appear in other browsers. Check my edit to my last comment.